# What is the best reply to accept an appointment of meeting to help

Tags: grammar

I was invited by email to a meeting to help the new excutive with my past experience
What should i say to accept this invitation?
Is "I am glad to be of help " is correct?

Comment: "I am glad to be of help" is fine.

Comment: Thank you for inviting me. I will be looking forward to meeting you soon...

Comment: When an executive writes to you, you need to respond immediately. That is more important than having a polished response. Don't wait around for advice from the internet.

Comment: Anything that expresses your willingness to help should be fine. No one is grading you on emails, especially if they know you're not a native English speaker. Just get the point across.